# process html form with asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net

I have the following table which sits inside an asp.net form. Im trying to process it using an onclick event on a button. but the elements are html text boxes and html check boxes all with names that are arrays

ive tried doing this

```
for(int i = 0; i < Request["pageimagesOrder"].Length; i++) 
{
      Response.Write(Request["pageimagesOrder"][i]);
}
```

but it just fell over. Im sure its something simple but like all things, there only simple if you know

thanks

```
<table>
      <tr>
        <td width="200"><img src="/CaptionImages/Thmbs/1.png" width="196" height="140" /></td>
        <td width="300" valign="top">caption txt 1</td>
        <td width="25" valign="top"><input style="width:20px;" type="text" name="pageimagesOrder[1]" value="1 "></td>
        <td width="100" valign="top"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="pageimagesDelete[]" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="200"><img src="/CaptionImages/Thmbs/2.png" width="196" height="140" /></td>
        <td width="300" valign="top">caption txt 1</td>
        <td width="25" valign="top"><input style="width:20px;" type="text" name="pageimagesOrder[2]" value="2 "></td>
        <td width="100" valign="top"><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="pageimagesDelete[]" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="200"><img src="/CaptionImages/Thmbs/3.png" width="196" height="140" /></td>
        <td width="300" valign="top">caption txt 1</td>
        <td width="25" valign="top"><input style="width:20px;" type="text" name="pageimagesOrder[3]" value="3 "></td>
        <td width="100" valign="top"><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="pageimagesDelete[]" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="200"><img src="/CaptionImages/Thmbs/5.png" width="196" height="140" /></td>
        <td width="300" valign="top">caption txt 1</td>
        <td width="25" valign="top"><input style="width:20px;" type="text" name="pageimagesOrder[5]" value="4 "></td>
        <td width="100" valign="top"><input type="checkbox" value="5" name="pageimagesDelete[]" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="200"><img src="/CaptionImages/Thmbs/7.png" width="196" height="140" /></td>
        <td width="300" valign="top">caption txt 2</td>
        <td width="25" valign="top"><input style="width:20px;" type="text" name="pageimagesOrder[7]" value="5 "></td>
        <td width="100" valign="top"><input type="checkbox" value="7" name="pageimagesDelete[]" /></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually naming them with the brackets []

If you write 
`Response.Write(Request["pageimagesOrder[1]"])` in code behind you will get a value.

Comment: the "1" refers to the id of the item, the table is generated dynamically so i need the 1 in there. its passing an array back which i need to loop through

Comment: i need to do something like this
foreach (string pageImagesOrder in Request.Form["pageimagesOrder"].ToString())
{

}

Comment: i need them as an array. the array index is the id in the tbl so I can loop them and get the value entered into the txt box

Comment: You may for example remove the brackets and write <input style="width:20px;" type="text" name="pageimagesOrder" value="5 "> Then it will become a comma separated string of the checked values which may processed it server side as foreach(string value in Request.Params["pageimagesOrder"].Split(','))

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do:

```
Response.Write(Request["pageimagesOrder[" + i + "]"]);
```

That'll give you the correct naming :)

Comment: the only problem is i dont know the value of i. its a table id from a db

Comment: You have it in your `for` loop?

Comment: With my **exact** code? I tried it and it compiles fine for me?

Comment: if I use a for loop the index starts at 0 I need to do it in a foreach loop something like this

foreach (string pp in Request["pageimagesOrder"])
            {
                Response.Write(pp);
            }

Comment: You can't do a `foreach` in this instance because you need to correctly index each item, which can only be done with a `for` loop.

Comment: think I will need to look at a different way of doing it